# First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty Hartl's Rails 4 Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, and I'm running into an issue in section 7.3.3.  I receive this error message:

```
ArgumentError in Users#new
Showing /Users/Anuraag/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #6 raised:
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

when I run the following rspec:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb -e "signup with invalid information"
```

at the following line:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
```

Here is my code.  Please also let me know how I should improve this question if I'm not framing it well: I'm pretty new to StackOverflow as well

app/views/users/new.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

app/assets/controllers/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      # Handle a successful save.
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the error message that you are receiving? Also, can you post the rspec example.

Comment: I made the edits you requested.  Do you have any insight now?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your `new.html.erb` you have specified `form_for(@user)` that means you need to have some value in instance variable `@user` before calling the `new` action.

You can do it in two ways :

one way is define an action `new` in your controller which would be called before rendering your `new.html.erb` layout. For eg:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

other way is that in your form itself you could specify something like

```
<%= form_for(User.new) do |f| %>
```

Defining it in your `new` action is more standard way of doing it.

Comment: doesn't my create action along with the private user_params definition in my controller take the place of the new action?  could you take a look at the section of the Rails tutorial I'm working off of?  It is in section 7.3.3 http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#top

Comment: Take a look at `Listing 7.18` where `new` action has been defined for `UsersController`. I think you missed that.

Comment: Thanks! :)  Could you explain to me why you need both that action and the subsequent code that I have?  It seems redundant to me

Comment: Please read about CRUD in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)     `new` is an action that renders your `new.html.erb` view whereas `create` is an action which is called when you submit the POST request via `new.html.erb`.

Comment: hi, when i am trying to add form with <%= form_for(User.new) do |f| %> its showing me error like:
ArgumentError in Pages#about :
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty.

what is this As i am new on ROR

Here is my form
<%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title, 'Title' %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %><br/>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :content, 'Content'%><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :content %><br/>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit "Add a New Post" %>
</p>
<% end %>

Comment: By adding `User.new` direct to form_for parameter fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The order of actions in controller file matters. I had the same error until I figure out the problem on order of action methods. 
Example.
Controller file

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update

end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

I was working on edit action and was getting same error as you. The problem was I have written the edit action under private action. once I changed the order of this actions. It worked like a charm.

What I was trying to achieve ?
I was trying to take the values of post instance variable and use it into html form.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a new action on you controller.

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

I maybe made indirectly, but it couldn't hurt defining it yourself.
From you title that may be why the @user variable is nil, it wasn't defined.

Comment: I thought that my 'add create' block took care of that...?

Comment: What 'add create'? In the controller? That is used after that users/new.html.erb view. You do need a new action in your controller.

Comment: Or maybe devise handles it, but try it above code, it should get rid of the nil error.

Comment: Why would devise handle it when OP is actually using its own controller `UsersController`

Comment: Thanks kirti for posting the same answer. But notice it did not error out in the controller giving an undefined new action so, something is indirectly creating it, it could be rails, cancan, devise, or some other gem.