# Hartl tutorial Chapter 9. "ArgumentError in UsersController#edit "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm completely new to Ruby and Rails, and working my way through the Hartl tutorial. I've Googled this error and come up with several similar (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804050/first-argument-in-form-cannot-contain-nil-or-be-empty-hartls-rails-4-tutorial) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918166/rails-edit-html-erb-argumenterror)), but the solutions posted to them don't help me.

As per tutorial instructions, my UsersController looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
.
.
.
```

So at this point, the `show` and `edit` actions are identical. The `show` action works fine (i.e. it shows the expected info about `@user`). But following the `edit` link gives the following error:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#edit
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #432):

    else
        object      = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record
        raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object
        object_name = options[:as] || model_name_from_record_or_class(object).param_key
        apply_form_for_options!(record, object, options)
    end
```

A little lower down the error page, there's the heading 'Request', saying

```
Parameters:
{"id"=>"1"}
```

... which seems to imply that the parameter is being passed, but for some reason the `@user` object isn't being retrieved from the database.

I've tried swapping the content of `edit.html.erb` with `show.html.erb`, and the result is that the `show` page now shows the edit form, correctly, and the `edit` link (now containing the `show` page, formerly working perfectly) throws an error because it firmly believes that the `@user` object is nil.

Any help/insights would be very much appreciated.

Edit: I really think I've eliminated this as a possible source of error, but for completeness' sake this is the `edit` form code:

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit user") %>
<h1>Update your profile</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="gravatar_edit">
      <%= gravatar_for @user %>
      <a href="http://gravatar.com/emails" target="_blank">change</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I've tried changing line 6 of the form code to this:

```
    <%= form_for(@user = User.find(params[:id])) do |f| %>
```

... and **then** it renders the page correctly. Although it doesn't answer the deeper question of "why the heck it doesn't work without this ugly hack."

Comment: What does your form look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the answer, and it was every bit as stupid as you'd imagine. Careless reading on my part. I failed to appreciate that `edit` and `update` were two separate operations: the controller labelled `def edit` in the first code block above was in fact labelled `def update`, and I was consistently reading it as `edit`.

So thanks to everyone who looked, particularly to spectre6000, whose link above made me take a longer look at the controller, and my sincere apologies for wasting your time.

On the plus side, I think I've understood more about Rails in the last six hours than in the previous two weeks of working through this tutorial.

Comment: Bummer. Even after working with rails for a while, it's something I skimmed right over without catching. Good find, though

Answer (score 1):

The the views are swapping like they are because there is a difference in the `show` and `edit` routes. The `show` route is `user/:id` where the `edit` route is `user/:id/edit` which expects a form.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html (see 2.2 CRUD, Verbs, and Actions)

I would look extra close at your `edit` view form, and maybe even try copy/pasting from the Hartl Listing 9.2 to find a particularly elusive typo.

`raise ArgumentError, "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty" unless object`
suggests object is not truthy (aka, it's `nil`).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've done the copy/paste thing from Hartl's listing, and it doesn't help. I agree with your guess that the `@user` object is somehow being set to nil, but I have no idea why, because precisely the same format works fine in calling the `show` page. The only difference I can see between them is in the links used to direct to the page, and I don't think that's the issue, because Ruby is finding the template OK and even passing the `Parameters` correctly if the error page is to be believed.